# How to add the time in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I have this following array of times (Hours:Minutes:Seconds)

```
$times = array("00:30:14", "00:20:04", "00:20:04", "01:00:00");
```

Now I need to add those times so the end result will be: **02:10:22**.
So far I've tried lot of solutions using strtotime and mktime() but no luck.. Here is what Im doing now but the result is always wrong

```
foreach ($data[0]->tweets as $key => $value)
{
    if($totalTime == 0)
        $totalTime = strtotime($value->timer_time);
    else
        $totalTime = strtotime($value->timer_time, $totalTime);
}                    

echo date("H:i:s", $totalTime);die;
```

Comment: About 30 seconds of Googling turned up http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: @GordonM : tried this one! doesn't work